# jquery active class works in code pen but not actual site?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to assign an active class to a clicked on li.

The code works perfectly in codepen and jsfiddle but not on my actual site.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qORBXb

On the site itself the content shows when the li is clicked, but the border-bottom does not show and when inspecting the code, the active class is not being set when clicked in.

jquery is loading fine as the other piece of code is working fine?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


   $('#wayfindermenu a').click(function(e){
     hideContentDivs();
     var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
     $('.maincontent div').eq(tmp_div).show();
  });

function hideContentDivs(){
    $('.maincontent div').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();});
}
hideContentDivs();
});

var selector = '#wayfindermenu li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: is there any error you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this

```
$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

is outside of DOMready wrapper, and perhaps codepen adds its own wrapper

**This is why indentation is important**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#wayfindermenu a').click(function(e){
       hideContentDivs();
       var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
       $('.maincontent div').eq(tmp_div).show();
    });

    function hideContentDivs(){
       // no need to iterate
       /*$('.maincontent div').each(function(){
           $(this).hide();
       });*/
       $('.maincontent div').hide();
    }

    hideContentDivs();

    // This also needs to be in the DOMready wrapper
    // but in any case, there's a better way to write this bit
    /*var selector = '#wayfindermenu li';
    $(selector).on('click', function(){
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });*/
    $('#wayfindermenu li').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

You should also declare your functions last for neatness.